# How to get ceil value with custom digit number in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my database, I have prices of items, and the discount percents for the items.

Here is a sample row from the database

```
Name     Price     DiscountPercent
****    1000.26         17.00
```

Now for this row I need to get the discounted price, but with two digits after the comma, i.e. for the discounted price 830.2158 I want to get 830.21

Doing

```
Round((UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * DiscountPercent)/100),2)
```

in my select query will return 830.22 which is not what I want. I could have achieved the desired result if I could do

```
Round(Floor((UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * DiscountPercent)/100) * 100)/100,2)
```

but unfortunately there is no Floor function in SQLite.

I also tried to cast to int and then divide by 100 and Round, but it seems that SQLite casts the whole result to int, because I get 830.0

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT cast(cast((UnitPrice - UnitPrice * DiscountPercent/100) * 100 as int) as real) / 100 FROM Product

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one is complicated and it is basically subtracting off the 3rd decimal place.

```
round((UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * DiscountPercent)/100)-(((UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * DiscountPercent)/100)%1*100)%1/100),2)
```

Easier to read and to get the basic Idea:

```
round(value -((value%1*100)%1/100),2)
```

Comment: do you mean using
SELECT Round(Round((UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * DiscountPercent)/100) * 100 , 0)/100,2) FROM Product ?
It returns 830.22 again

Comment: Yes if you still want the `.00` after the int

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help

Comment: How? if you want 830.00 that is the result it gives

Comment: as I mentioned above, i want 830.21

Comment: finally I did it. Here is the way i solved it, but i don't like it and still looking for a better answer

SELECT cast(cast((UnitPrice - UnitPrice * DiscountPercent/100) * 100 as int) as real) / 100 FROM Product